# IBM Lotus Notes how to indicate the view column number in columnvalues

Tags: java, c#, lotus-notes

I'm now working on a project of IBM lotus notes plugin, using C#.

Here's request that we want to get the data from view by view column's name, such as "Date".

I found that I can use the method "GetColumn" in "NotesView" class to get the info of column name and other basic info, but the real data are not included in it.
To get the data , I need to use the attributes "ColumnValues" in "ViewEntry" class or "Document" class.

Unfortunately, regarding the technical documents provided by IBM, there are several cases that not all the column values will be return.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_COLUMNVALUES_PROPERTY_JAVA.html

For example , the result of GetColumn is 16 columns, and the 12th column's name is "Date", it's datetime type. But in the ColumnValues, there's only 13 columns, no column names, and the 8th columns type is datetime which seems to be the "Date" column.

I've tried to figure out which kinds of the columns will be omitted.
Firstly, I tried to catch the "UI-only function" in formula, but it seems not enough. Secondly, I tried to catch "constant", but don't how. Finally I found that not all the "constant" formula columns are deleted. I abandoned.

Is there anyone who can help me to indicate the view column number in columnvalues ?

Comment: The best practice is to have views for programmatic access separate from views for UI access. The programmatic access view should not have the columns that are not included in column values. Then your code will be simpler to develop.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "plugin". What type of plugin? How and where does it run? Plugins that run within the eclipse-based client UI environment are, to the best of my knowledge, written in Java, not C#. And also, please explain why you believe you should be accessing values through the columnValues in the views instead of accessing the values through NotesItems in the documents. (There are sometimes good reasons for this, but I often see people trying to do it when it would be much simpler to just use the NotesDocuments and NotesItems.

Comment: @Newbs Thank you for your logical idea. My problem is really what you said: currently I can only find the view values for programmatic access, but no view names for programmatic access, so I could not complete the indication.Do you know how to get the view column names for programmatic access in Lotus Notes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the universal approach you want to use (letting the user select the column by selecting the title), you would be better served using the Columns property of the NotesView object, then iterate the view where your desired documents reside, and for the selected view columns:

- If the **vwcol.IsField** property is True, return `doc.GetItemValue(vwcol.ItemName)`
- If the **vwcol.IsField** property is False (**vwcol.IsFormula** = True), return `Evaluate(vwcol.Formula, doc)`

Answer (score 0):

@RichardSchwartz I have used C++ to create a menu item in notes, which will call the real notes app outside, then I called them as "plugin" as total. IBM introduce LotusScript and Java as non-COM and COM (Windows technical), the C# and Java are both supported via COM, but as they provide the same features, Java are mainly described on IBM , no C# docs.For C++, it has docs in the Notes C++ development kit ,which is a nsf.

There are 2 reasons why I want to get the value in view instead of lookup the values inside the NotesDocument:

1. Visibility for user.
   The user could not see the item name in the NotesDocument(such as textbox_1), but they can see the column name directly on the view, and this name can indicate the column (but not column value).
2. Universality.
   For different DB and the item with same meaning, not only the item name will be different, but also the item value will be different. If you lookup the value in NotesDoument, then probably your program can only work for only 1 db.
   For example , the value "Approve State" in one DB's docs are "Checked,Approved", and the same words shown in the view.  But for another DB, the values of "Approve State" in one DB's are "1,2,3", the Formula of the view column judge the value"1,2,3"and finally shows "Checked,Approved".